# Angular unit-testing mock paramMap get

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I've component which represents an item from a list and to get this item I use `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')`. How do I mock this?
I've tried

```
providers: [
                {
                    provide: ActivatedRoute,
                    useValue: { snapshot: { params: convertToParamMap({ id: '1' }) } }
                }
            ]
```

But this results in

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are providing

`{ snapshot: { params: convertToParamMap({ id: '1' }) }`
 so its `snapshot.params`

while you try ti access it via `this.route.snapshot.paramMap`

as you can see, there is no `paramMap`in your mock.

The fact that you are providing object as "value" does not mean that this object will automatically become instance of `ActivatedRoute`. Its just what you defined - plain object. There is no runtime type controll, so this is allowed.

You can simply provide partial implementation, something like

```
 useValue: { snapshot: { paramMap: {get:(id:number)=>{id:1}}}}
```

or make getter for this property in your component - this will allow you to `spy` on that getter call, intercept it and return required value.

Comment: How do I stub this `this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(map(params => params.get('page') || 1)).subscribe`. I've tried `queryParamMap: of(convertToParamMap({page: '23'}))` but it causes an error 'unexpected value'

Comment: also, could you be so kind and provide some link where I could learn unit testing in Angular? angular.io looks a bit overwhelming and providing information so that you do a helper function AtiavatedRouteStub and don't know where and how to use it.

Comment: `this.route.queryParamMap` this can be for example `Observable.of(params)`

Comment: Thank you x 1000

Comment: Thanks this worked with a slight variation! In my case I had to write this: ````get: (id: string) => {return '3';},````. Be aware that you cannot omit the return statement, if the function block is not on one line (in my case due to the prettier extension).